# Backbone.js PushState True

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate

I've created a site in backbone and for various reasons I've decided I want to remove the hash in the URL. I've changed history.start from

```html
Backbone.history.start();
```

to

```html
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/'});
```

but once I do that the routing stops working correctly.

My routing looks like this:

```js
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "home",
    "home": "home",
    "artists": "artists",
  }
});

var router = new Router;
router.on('route:home', function() {
  console.log("home");
  // Code
});

router.on('route:artists', function() {
  console.log("artists");
  // Code
});

//Backbone.history.start();
Backbone.history.start({
  pushState: true,
  root: '/'
});
```

if I run it without pushState it works fine, if I run it with pushState it doesn't reach the `console.log("artists");` part and I don't understand why, could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to prevent `a` element to carry on its regular action and have backbone router route it.

I'll write the example using jQuery to outline what should happen:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // This is important

    var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');

    router.navigate(href, true); // <- this part will pass the path to your router

});
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks. Does something else have to be added to handle things if you go to the link directly? If I go directly to /artists then nothing seems to load, whereas if I go to the home page and navigate to /artists it works fine. I'm guessing I've left something else like that out?

Comment: If you want to be able to paste a link like `http://yoursite.com/artists` into your browser's address bar then you need to configure your web server to direct all requests to the page that bootstraps backbone and the router. Otherwise the web server will try to load that resource, and what you want is backbone to pick that up and perform its own routing. If you can mention which web server you use, I might be able to help out with the configuration.

Comment: @mrdookles you need to ensure you have server routing  to handle your front-end app routing.  It's failing because the server doesn't redirect to app/index.html

Comment: Also, the method in my answer will route all `a` elements to backbone router. You might want to have certain links (like to external sites or bootstrap tabs) to behave as normal. Consider making a distinction between the two. For `a` elements that I want to handle using Backbone.Router, I usually give them a `data` attribute such as `data-bbroutable="true"` so that I can avoid interfering with other `a` elements.

Comment: Really you shouldn't be using navigate with trigger true to transition between you applications view states.  The router should only be responsible for updating the URL.  Backbone is designed to be event based and App state transition should be managed via events and controllers.  The routes are generally only required to handle URL / bookmark navigation.

Comment: Why is the necessity to trap  <a> element click event not mentioned in the official backbone documentation?

Comment: @RobertMoskal - I don't know exactly, but it seems logical to me that you need to do that, even if the documentation doesn't mention it. The docs just tell us how to modify the browser's address bar and how to navigate to certain route. Now, you can do that by clicking <a> elements or using some other mechanism. If you use <a> elements, it makes sense that you need to prevent their default action.

Answer (score 3):

Now I see why the need to globally override the  tag behavior isn't in the documentation. I think we are intended to use handle navigation in our views like so:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click a.foo": "foo"
  },

  foo: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    history.navigate("foo");
    $("#output").append("foo");
  }
});
```

However if we want to retain the option to use simple HREFs in our  tags we have to intercept the click behavior as in the above.

If you have a hybrid app, some links internal to backbone, and some forcing a page refresh, it's not right to preventDefault() for every link.  Links to other parts of the app will be broken.

One can use a variation of the above and take advantage of the fact that if there is no internal view to navigate to, Backbone.history.navigate() will return false.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e)
{

    var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');

    var res = Backbone.history.navigate(href,true);
    //if we have an internal route don't call the server
    if(res)
        e.preventDefault();

});
```