# Backbone router: how to set up hrefs to connect to router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I see a lot of examples with just some router code and that's it. My href in my HTML must start with a "#" so the page doesn't redirect, correct?
So let's say my a tag looks like so:

```
<a href="/#login">Login</a>
```

What should the route look like in the router?

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
   "login": "loginAction"
  },

  loginAction: function(){
   // do cool stuff
  }
});
```

Does the route above need the hash or any kind of backslash? 
Or should my href in my anchor be `"/#/login"` ?

Also, I've seen this code

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true
});
```

What does this mean and what does it do?
Do I use this code after or before I create a new instance of my router?

Comment: The route reacts on the part after the `#`, so the first example is OK. Note that the slash before the `#` might be wrong if your application does not run in the root directory. Consider leaving paths off (`#login`), it should be OK in 99.9% of all cases.

Comment: With `pushState:true`, you no longer need `#` in the url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323836/backbone-js-pushstate-true

Answer (score 0):

I have another small hack for you.
First define your links as usual

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

than before starting the Backbone Router, call this jQuery snippet

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="/"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
  Backbone.history.navigate(href, { trigger: true });
});
```

what does this snippet do, is only block redirection of all href, and let the Backbone router take the job for you (without refresh).

```
var router = new App.Router();
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}); // Start the Router
```