# Root relative url not working in anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, anchor, relative-path

I have a webpage at a certain url, say `https://example.com/foo/bar/xyz`

In this said page, I have multiple anchor tags with root relative paths, e.g. `<a href="/blah/rand/abc">Link 1</a>`

Now when I hover over these links, my browser shows a valid preview of them, i.e., it shows `https://example.com/blah/rand/abc` which is expected, but on clicking them, I get routed to `https://example.com/foo/blah/rand/abc`

I find this behavior very strange and I have verified that the html served at the original url does not have any `<base>` tag in the head section. Is there any other way to control the base path for a relative url?

What's also strange is that there are a bunch of css files loaded through their root-relative paths, and they seem to be loading fine. So, I suspect something in the javascript on the page to be interfering with these. Also to add context, this is a SPA built on backbone.js - so the base html returned by url mentioned in line 1, just returns a skeleton html with a div where the actual app is initialized - which is where these buggy anchor tags eventually turn up.

Comment: You can check if there are JS listeners easily in Chrome debug tools, see pic here https://ibb.co/mQd0pQ please

Comment: Also if you eventually using Chaplin ( http://chaplinjs.org/ ) which is built over Backbone, then it definetely handles each link click

Comment: Without a [mcve], we won't be able to pinpoint the problem, only throwing guesses until you actually find the problem on your end.

Comment: That being said, here's my guess: Check for a [link click listener needed for Backbone `pushState`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28323836/1218980).