# Configure node express for Backbone SPA with pushState

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backbone.js, url-routing

My express app has a rest server and a SPA using Backbone. All works fine using # history, i.e.

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

If I do:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

the Backbone router ceases to work - a route that Backbone handles fine (e.g. #route) gets sent to Express when it becomes /route. Express errors with:

```
Cannot GET /route
```

I tried:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root '/' });
```

but no difference.

I also tried:

```
app.use('/*', function ...
```

in Express - no difference.

express server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

var rest = require('./routes/rest');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/rest', rest);

app.listen(3000);
```

The Backbone router (slimmed a bit):

```
const Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': Controllers.home,
    'admin(/:table)(/:id)': Controllers.admin,
    'master(/:table)(/:id)': Controllers.master
  }
});
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

I don't need any SEO, I'd just like to get shot of those '#' in the app's routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the router is working fine. It's "not working" when you are calling directly `/index.html/someroute` from the browser instead of the app.

To handle this you have to catch it in express

```
app.get('*', function...)
```

should work.

Be sure to declare the other route first (like `/rest`) otherwise it will be caught by `'*'` before reaching `'/rest'`. This is due to the middleware pattern express is using (just a reminder you may already know this).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, that's it - just need to make sure I'm catching all the clicks on hrefs now (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28324267/2060804)